# 'pip' not working outside of virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtual-environment

I am being able to run **pip** commands inside a virtual environment. However, on using this outside the virtual environment, I get the following error:

> -bash: pip: command not found

Any idea on what is wrong and how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the default version of Python in your system? Is it python2 or python3?

Comment: @taurus05 os- MAC 10.9 (Mavericks). Python -V: 2.7.8; python3 -V: Python 3.7.1

Comment: If both python2.x and python3.x are present in the system and are accessible without using virtual env, then you should try installing pip for the version of your choice. It might be that pip was uninstalled accidently.

Comment: But if it was uninstalled, then how is it running inside the virtual environment?

Comment: @Mihika, I have added an answer to your question, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `pip` outside of the virtual environment you need to install it on your system. This will require super-user permissions.

Assuming you're on Linux, you can install `pip` for Python 3 as follows:

```sh
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

Using `pip` outside of a virtual env will require `sudo` when you want to install new packages. However, you should use a virtual env if possible since it encapsulates the project requirements and doesn't require super-user permissions.

Comment: Since when using pip requires sudo?

Comment: Outside the venv, always :)

Comment: What's the drawback of using `--user` to avoid using sudo with pip?

Answer (score 1):

usually pip comes with the default python, either you don't have the default python, or not set in your environment path,

I would suggest first to check if you have python by typing these following commands

`python --version`

for python 3

`python3 --version`

then install pip for which ever version you have by using the correspoding commands

`sudo apt-get install python-pip`

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

for python3

this is only applicable to ubuntu or debian systems

Comment: Yes, I do have python installed. python --version: 2.7.8 and python3 --version: 3.7.1. If pip is not installed, then how is it working for virtual environments?

Comment: Virtual env has its own copy python interpreter along with other packages. It has nothing to do with the copy of python installed on your system outside virtual env.

Comment: Thanks, this answers it. I reinstalled pip using "sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip", and it is working now

Answer (score 1):

First, `pip` is [already installed](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) if you are using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4. It seems you have it installed for your version of Python 3 (3.7.1 according to your comment in your answer), but it might not be installed in your version of Python 2 (2.7.8).

Second, you can install `pip` in your Python 2 version running the following command:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

and assuming that when running `python` you use Python 2, run:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Third, your version of `pip` in Python 3 is probably called `pip3`, so you could run `which pip3` to verify it.

Fourth, `pip` is a Python package, so you can always access it using the following commands:

```
python -m pip # for Python 2
python3 -m pip # for Python 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try pip3 ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l25Zw.png)).

```
pip3 --version
```